# Tripplite KVM switch loosesUSB connection Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: usb, 19.10

I have a Tripp Lite KVM switch; 4 port with 3.0 USB Hub. The problem is, that my dell XPS 9560 sometimes randomly looses the connection with the hub. Mouse, Keyboard etc. stops working. The USB hub light on the switch starts blinking, as if no usb device was connected and after a few seconds its going back to work.

This problem started with 19.10, my old 17.10 didn't have this problem. I work extensively with this setup (30 hours a week), so I'm confident the problem is connected with my ubuntu upgrade.

Since a simple "Whats the problem?" most likely won't get an answer I go with: How can I narrow down the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution: Disable the autosuspend function (article I used https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-usb-device-port-linux/)

Important part, in case article goes down:

Check if autosuspend is active:

```
cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend
```

If this returns `2` autosuspend is active. After that you can follow the instructions of this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91027/how-to-disable-usb-autosuspend-on-kernel-3-7-10-or-above (which gives some further explanation)